# Advise with Good Design Patterns When Connecting To An External Database?

Tags: java, android, mongodb, design-patterns

I have a regular app using `sqlite`. I am using a singleton to have a connection to it and perform **CRUD** operations from it.

I do want to use this with an external database where I would download txt files. I have a database using mongolab and I do know that they have a tutorial to connect directly to the database but I am wondering if this is the right option for me.

What is a good design pattern to connect and keep a connection with an external database such as mongo.

Would it be better to connect to my hosting site and build an API and make calls from android to my API?

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward answer is yes.

A common way of not only speeding up, but also acquiring more stability is to have your architecture delegate the database connections to a stable server.

In this case, your suggestion of building an API through which your application will indirectly query the database is the good one.